# HTML Break Table Columns (TD) To Multiple Rows On Small Screens

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a html table:

```
<table>
<tr> <td>data...</td>  <td>data...</td>  <td>data...</td> </tr>
</table>
```

This shows as:

```
-------------------------
|data...|data...|data...|
-------------------------
```

which is fine on large screens, but what i want is to break the columns into multiple rows as needed if the screen is small.

So when needed the table would show as:

```
----------
|data....|
|--------|
|data....|
|--------|
|data....|
----------
```

Is there a way to do this with something like css?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change to `display: table-row` with media queries [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/840/)

```css
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  td {
    display: table-row;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr> <td>data...</td>  <td>data...</td>  <td>data...</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use display:block as for break the column
```

```
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  td {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr> <td>data...</td>  <td>data...</td>  <td>data...</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the td as display block and give the width as 100%.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
th,td { display:block; width:100%; }
  }
```

```html
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>#</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```