# Break whole table columns on small screens with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design

I have an html `<table>` that looks like this:

```
-------------------------
| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
-------------------------
| Foo A | Bar A | Buzz A|
|-------|-------|-------|
| Foo B | Bar B | Buzz B|
-------------------------
```

For responsiveness, it should be broken up into individual columns on small screens like this:

```
---------
| Col 1 |
---------
| Foo A |
| ----- |
| Foo B |
---------

---------
| Col 2 |
---------
| Bar A |
| ----- |
| Bar B |
---------

---------
| Col 3 |
---------
| Buzz A|
|-------|
| Buzz B|
---------
```

**Is there a trick to break up the columns with pure CSS**, or will I need to use JS (or hardcode both versions of the table and use CSS just to choose which one is `display`ed?)**?**

---

There are similar questions on this platform already (like [HTML Break Table Columns (TD) To Multiple Rows On Small Screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254347/html-break-table-columns-td-to-multiple-rows-on-small-screens)), but they usually rely on setting the individual table cells to `display:block;`, which would mess up the order in this case.)

Comment: May I ask, are there any row headings? Because without those, this looks more like a series of lists, nested or otherwise.

Comment: There are no row headings, but I want table-like vertical alignment between the entries. (This is supposed to be a 3-day event schedule, and entires on happening at the same different days time should be vertically aligned.)

Comment: To me that reads like you have three lists, one for each day rather than any tabular data. Thank, that makes the layout and CSS easier to manage.

Comment: How would you then ensure vertical alignment between specific entries? That's the only reason that keeps me from ditching the `<table>`.